# kotlin room livedata list value is always null

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I retrieve list from config firebase i insert them on database with room framework, i want to use livedata to notify mainactivity that the data are fetched from firebase and after from database everything work i retrieve simple data to check that data are stocked on database but when i retrieve livedata list, their value are always nul

here what i tried

MainActivity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    questionsViewModel.listQuestions!!.observe(this, Observer<List<Question>>{
        // The second call it is null  
        if(it != null) {
         // we enter never here is always null
        }
    })


    questionsViewModel.getListQuestion()
}
```

QuestionsViewModel :

```
 class QuestionsViewModel(private val questionRepo: QuestionRepository, val c : Context) : ViewModel(),
KoinComponent {


var listQuestions : MutableLiveData<List<Question>> = MutableLiveData<List<Question>>()
var question : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    listQuestions.value = listOf()
}

fun getListQuestion(){

    questionRepo.getQuestion({ listQuestionsFromDatabase ->
        this.listQuestions.value  = listQuestionsFromDatabase.value

    },{_ ->


    })
}
```

QuestionRepository :

```
class QuestionRepository(private val questionService: QuestionService){

fun getQuestion(onSuccess: (listQuestions: LiveData<List<Question>>) -> Unit,
                        onError: (error: String) -> Unit) {

    questionService.getListQuestionNonAsked({ listQuestions ->
        onSuccess(listQuestions)
    },{error ->


    })
}
```

}

QuestionService :

```
public fun getListQuestionNonAsked (
onSuccess: (listQuestions: LiveData<List<Question>>) -> Unit,
onError: (error: String) -> Unit) {



    remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful)                {


            var listQuestion =  remoteConfig.getString("questions_sport_vf")

            val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)

            try {

                val serializer = Questions.serializer()
                val questionsRecuperer : Questions = Json.nonstrict.parse(serializer, listQuestion)

                val version = questionsRecuperer.version.toInt()
                val versionFromPref = prefHandle.versionDatabaseLocal




                if(versionFromPref < version){

                    // On insere dans la base de donnee
                    // On vide la database et on insere les nouvelle donnees



                    //val questiondao = database?.questionDao()
                    database?.questionDao()?.deleteAll()


                    database?.questionDao()?.insertList(questionsRecuperer.data)


                }
   // Just for test listdata witout livedata are retrieven 
                val z = database!!.questionDao().getDataList()
  // this is my problem the value is null
                val a = database!!.questionDao().getData()
 // this value is null
                val b = a.value
                 onSuccess(database!!.questionDao().getData())

            }catch (e : Exception){
                print(e.stackTrace)
                onError(e.stackTrace.toString())
            }

        } else {


        }
    }




}
```

QuestionDao :

```
  @Dao
   abstract class QuestionDao : BaseDao<Question> {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM Question")
    abstract fun getData(): LiveData<List<Question>>

  @Query("DELETE  FROM Question")
  abstract fun deleteAll()


constructor()

@Query("SELECT * FROM Question")
abstract fun getDataList(): List<Question>

}
```

AppDatabase :

```
 @Database(entities = arrayOf(Question::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
  abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(), KoinComponent {
  abstract fun questionDao(): QuestionDao



companion object {

    private var APPDATABASE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
        if (APPDATABASE == null) {
            synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                APPDATABASE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "questionQuizzVraiFaux.db").allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
        }
        return APPDATABASE
    }
 }


 }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my QuestionService

to return a List instead of LiveData>

and on QuestionsViewModel 
var listQuestions : MutableLiveData> = MutableLiveData>()

i do this.listQuestions.value = listQuestionsFromDatabase
instead of this.listQuestions.value  = listQuestionsFromDatabase.value

and after that i enter on

questionsViewModel.listQuestions!!.observe(this, Observer>{
            if(it != null) {
             // we enter never here is always null
            }
        })

with : it contains all elements from database

i don't know why livedata from database are null

Answer (score 1):

> kotlin room livedata list value is always null

It is always `null` because you trying to observe a `LiveData` object which is not yet instantiated. To solve this please change the order of line codes as follows:

```
questionsViewModel.getListQuestion() //Called first
questionsViewModel.listQuestions!!.observe(this, Observer<List<Question>>{
    // The second call it is null  
    if(it != null) {
     // we enter never here is always null
    }
})
```

So you first need to get (instantiate) the `LiveData` object and after that, you can observe it.

Comment: i try it, when i init   listQuestions.value = listOf(), observe is called, but the second tilme when i set with this :  listQuestions.value = listQuestionsFromDatabase.value, observe is not called

Comment: Good to hear that `observe()` is called. Is your list now not-null? Does it contain the list of questions?

Comment: called the first time on init but not in the second time, first time is empty, second time it is not called

Comment: When you get the `List<Question>` from the database, is it filled with `Question` objects?

Comment: yes with abstract fun getDataList(): List<Question> i get list question from database